# Column Names faint or invisible for python Datatable view() on MacOS

Tags: python, py-datatable

I'm giving the `H2O` `datatable` a try and am intrigued by the `view()` feature. It looks like a handy way to navigate a dataset:

[image]

The navigator is great: you can use `g2000` to go to row 2000 .  But the column headers are faint - almost invisible. The image above is on macos `terminal`. Below is `iTerm`: and the headers *are* invisible there:

[image: or]

Given my interest to make the `datatable.view()` an integral part of my development process - since I prefer `ipython` to `jupyter notebooks` it would be helpful to find a solution to this. Has anyone discovered maybe a terminal setting or two that would help?

Comment: This wouldn't be fixing the core problem, but maybe try turning the terminal to dark mode via Preferences, and the column header will become more visible?

Comment: not a bad idea to play with the terminal themes: will report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been reported before (see https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/1793), but it was fixed in datatable v0.9.0 released in July 2019.

[image]

One possibility why you may still see faint colors is that your terminal preferences could be misspecified. Please check your terminal preferences and make sure the "Bold Text" is set to the color that has high contrast with your terminal's background.

[image]

Comment: thx Pasha for checking in!  Been watching progress of the `datatable` since 2017 and  it's sufficiently superior to `dataframe` to make the jump.  btw is `groupby` on expressions (not just columns list) in the near future?

Comment: It's not in the near future, however, it is in the near past. Group-by-expression is available since v0.10.0. See tracking issue https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/1383

Comment: awesome! for me that was the killer feature looking for to make a wholesale switch

Answer (score 1):

Based on suggestion/comment from @GreenCloakGuy I have tried out applying different `Profiles` to the `Terminal` window.  This is a working solution. In addition I learnt that pressing `CMD-I` allows *dynamic* switching of profiles in `Terminal`. That's useful!

[image]